# Implementations for common dimension reduction algorithms

Tags: visualization, dimension-reduction

I am working on a visualization manuscript that uses dimensional reduction with tSNE of a very large data set (227,573 points x 2,571 features).  The reviewers would like figures comparing the tSNE projections with other common methods of dimension reduction, aside from PCA.  Unfortunately,  MMA does not have implementations that I can find of specific dimension reduction methods commonly compared and cited in the field [Sammon maps, local linear embedding (LLE), ISOmap to be specific], and readily available in R, Matlab, and Python.

I have written implementations for metric and non-metric multidimensional scaling (found [here](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2015/09/graphical-representation-of-proximity-measures-for-multidimensional-data/) with code for any fellow travelers), but am hoping somebody has developed these in MMA to save hours of coding.

**Does anybody know of MMA implementations/code for these methods [Sammon maps, local linear embedding (LLE), ISOmap]?**

That said, I am a bit frustrated with the long lag in MMA implementation of methods in dimension reduction, graph theory (love Szabolcs iGraph implementation), and machine learning (better, but idiosyncratic in MMA 11).

Comment: @AntonAntonov   Perhaps only "common" in the work that I do.  Please forgive my extrapolation to the larger world!  I also meant "common" in the sense that R, Python, and Matlab communities have all cross-coded these methods (and many others), which have been available for several years in libraries.  This becomes a problem when I work mostly in MMA (and would like to continue to do so), but need to use such methods when I publish.

Comment: So revised.  Thanks!

Comment: If it is implemented in MatLab, you can use MatLink to communicate with MatLab - provided that you also get access to a MatLab license.

Comment: Note also that there is RLink...

Comment: And Pythonika...